# Error searching documents in Alfresco from Java application

Tags: java, alfresco

I have:

- Alfresco 4.0.d
- My Java application

I am running the SDK examples, but when I executed a search it throws an error:

**MY CODE:**

```
// Get a reference to the respository web service
RepositoryServiceSoapBindingStub repositoryService =WebServiceFactory.getRepositoryService(); 
// Create a query object, looking for all items with alfresco in
// the name of text 
Query query = new Query(Constants.QUERY_LANG_LUCENE, "TEXT:'alfresco development team'");
// Execute the  query
QueryResult queryResult = repositoryService.query(STORE, query, false);
```

**ERROR  STACKTRACE I AM GETTING:**

```
12:54:53,341 ERROR [stderr] (http-/172.31.46.157:443-2) AxisFault

12:54:53,341 ERROR [stderr] (http-/172.31.46.157:443-2)  faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.generalException

12:54:53,342 ERROR [stderr] (http-/172.31.46.157:443-2)  faultSubcode: 

12:54:53,342 ERROR [stderr] (http-/172.31.46.157:443-2)  faultString: 

12:54:53,342 ERROR [stderr] (http-/172.31.46.157:443-2)  faultActor: 

12:54:53,342 ERROR [stderr] (http-/172.31.46.157:443-2)  faultNode: 

12:54:53,342 ERROR [stderr] (http-/172.31.46.157:443-2)  faultDetail: 

12:54:53,343 ERROR [stderr] (http-/172.31.46.157:443-2)     {http://www.alfresco.org/ws/service/repository/1.0}RepositoryFault:<ns1:errorCode>0</ns1:errorCode><ns1:message>org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.lucene.LuceneQueryParserException: 0119124234 Request failed 404 /solr/alfresco/alfresco?wt=json&amp;fl=DBID%2Cscore&amp;rows=2147483647&amp;df=TEXT&amp;start=0&amp;locale=es_EC&amp;fq=%7B%21afts%7DAUTHORITY_FILTER_FROM_JSON&amp;fq=%7B%21afts%7DTENANT_FILTER_FROM_JSON</ns1:message>

12:54:53,343 ERROR [stderr] (http-/172.31.46.157:443-2)     {}exceptionName:org.alfresco.repo.webservice.repository.RepositoryFault

12:54:53,344 ERROR [stderr] (http-/172.31.46.157:443-2)     {}stackTrace:
12:54:53,344 ERROR [stderr] (http-/172.31.46.157:443-2)     at org.alfresco.repo.webservice.repository.RepositoryWebService.executeQuery(RepositoryWebService.java:170)
12:54:53,344 ERROR [stderr] (http-/172.31.46.157:443-2)     at org.alfresco.repo.webservice.repository.RepositoryWebService.query(RepositoryWebService.java:189)
12:54:53,345 ERROR [stderr] (http-/172.31.46.157:443-2)     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
12:54:53,345 ERROR [stderr] (http-/172.31.46.157:443-2)     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
12:54:53,345 ERROR [stderr] (http-/172.31.46.157:443-2)     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
12:54:53,345 ERROR [stderr] (http-/172.31.46.157:443-2)     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
12:54:53,346 ERROR [stderr] (http-/172.31.46.157:443-2)     at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.invokeMethod(RPCProvider.java:397)
12:54:53,347 ERROR [stderr] (http-/172.31.46.157:443-2)     at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.processMessage(RPCProvider.java:186)
12:54:53,347 ERROR [stderr] (http-/172.31.46.157:443-2)     at org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.invoke(JavaProvider.java:323)
12:54:53,351 ERROR [stderr] (http-/172.31.46.157:443-2)     at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
12:54:53,351 ERROR [stderr] (http-/172.31.46.157:443-2)     at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
12:54:53,355 ERROR [stderr] (http-/172.31.46.157:443-2)     at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
12:54:53,356 ERROR [stderr] (http-/172.31.46.157:443-2)     at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.SOAPService.invoke(SOAPService.java:454)
12:54:53,356 ERROR [stderr] (http-/172.31.46.157:443-2)     at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.invoke(AxisServer.java:281)
12:54:53,360 ERROR [stderr] (http-/172.31.46.157:443-2)     at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:699)
12:54:53,360 ERROR [stderr] (http-/172.31.46.157:443-2)     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
12:54:53,366 ERROR [stderr] (http-/172.31.46.157:443-2)     at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
12:54:53,366 ERROR [stderr] (http-/172.31.46.157:443-2)     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
12:54:53,370 ERROR [stderr] (http-/172.31.46.157:443-2)     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
12:54:53,370 ERROR [stderr] (http-/172.31.46.157:443-2)     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
12:54:53,374 ERROR [stderr] (http-/172.31.46.157:443-2)     at org.alfresco.web.app.servlet.GlobalLocalizationFilter.doFilter(GlobalLocalizationFilter.java:61)
12:54:53,375 ERROR [stderr] (http-/172.31.46.157:443-2)     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
12:54:53,375 ERROR [stderr] (http-/172.31.46.157:443-2)     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
12:54:53,379 ERROR [stderr] (http-/172.31.46.157:443-2)     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
12:54:53,379 ERROR [stderr] (http-/172.31.46.157:443-2)     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
12:54:53,384 ERROR [stderr] (http-/172.31.46.157:443-2)     at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
12:54:53,385 ERROR [stderr] (http-/172.31.46.157:443-2)     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
12:54:53,389 ERROR [stderr] (http-/172.31.46.157:443-2)     at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
12:54:53,389 ERROR [stderr] (http-/172.31.46.157:443-2)     at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
12:54:53,393 ERROR [stderr] (http-/172.31.46.157:443-2)     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
12:54:53,393 ERROR [stderr] (http-/172.31.46.157:443-2)     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
12:54:53,394 ERROR [stderr] (http-/172.31.46.157:443-2)     at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
12:54:53,399 ERROR [stderr] (http-/172.31.46.157:443-2)     at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
12:54:53,399 ERROR [stderr] (http-/172.31.46.157:443-2)     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1813)
12:54:53,403 ERROR [stderr] (http-/172.31.46.157:443-2)     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
12:54:53,404 ERROR [stderr] (http-/172.31.46.157:443-2)     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
12:54:53,407 ERROR [stderr] (http-/172.31.46.157:443-2)     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
12:54:53,408 ERROR [stderr] (http-/172.31.46.157:443-2) 

12:54:53,408 ERROR [stderr] (http-/172.31.46.157:443-2)     {}hostname:WIN-LPOT1P34Q84

12:54:53,408 ERROR [stderr] (http-/172.31.46.157:443-2) 

12:54:53,411 ERROR [stderr] (http-/172.31.46.157:443-2) 

12:54:53,412 ERROR [stderr] (http-/172.31.46.157:443-2)     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

12:54:53,412 ERROR [stderr] (http-/172.31.46.157:443-2)     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)

12:54:53,417 ERROR [stderr] (http-/172.31.46.157:443-2)     at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)

12:54:53,418 ERROR [stderr] (http-/172.31.46.157:443-2)     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)

12:54:53,422 ERROR [stderr] (http-/172.31.46.157:443-2)     at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)

12:54:53,422 ERROR [stderr] (http-/172.31.46.157:443-2)     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)

12:54:53,422 ERROR [stderr] (http-/172.31.46.157:443-2)     at org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.BeanDeserializer.<init>(BeanDeserializer.java:104)

12:54:53,423 ERROR [stderr] (http-/172.31.46.157:443-2)     at org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.BeanDeserializer.<init>(BeanDeserializer.java:90)

12:54:53,426 ERROR [stderr] (http-/172.31.46.157:443-2)     at org.alfresco.webservice.repository.RepositoryFault.getDeserializer(RepositoryFault.java:146)
```

Comment: Looks like you're passing in an invalid query string. What's the query you're trying to execute?

Comment: this is the query:                                                 // Get a reference to the respository web service
         RepositoryServiceSoapBindingStub repositoryService = WebServiceFactory.getRepositoryService();         
         
// Create a query object, looking for all items with alfresco in the name of text Query query = new Query(Constants.QUERY_LANG_LUCENE, "TEXT:'alfresco development team'")// Execute the que query                                              QueryResult queryResult = repositoryService.query(STORE, query, false);

Comment: You'd be best off to edit the question with that, it's quite hard to read in a comment

Comment: Query query = new Query(Constants.QUERY_LANG_LUCENE, "TEXT:'alfresco development team'"

Comment: Seems that Solr responds with a 404 - Is you Solr up & running? Can you perform the same query via NodeBrowser successfully?

Comment: thanks I `ve already solve this problem, I disabler solr in the alfresco.global